# Web user mesaurement process

Tags: data-mining, classification, web-analytics, user-tracking

How is high accuracy profiling of website users obtained? Is it a classification problem? How are attributes like age, sex and job derived from users visiting a website? For example, Quantcast Measurement provides website owners this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visiting a website only reveals a few statistics like IP address and [browser settings](https://panopticlick.eff.org/). The demographics  (age, sex, job) shown by, e.g., Quantcast Measurement are inferred using [huge panels](http://www.tvweek.com/news/2008/09/quantcast_delves_into_demograp.php) of internet users. Combining the website visit information with the data from the user panels results in a more in-depth view of the users which visit your website. This information is of course not entirely accurate (since you only a fraction of the visitors is on the panel), but it will give a good approximation.

Comment: Thanks !!, its cool to combine online data with some offline or small surveys to infer stuff.